# Assign month name and integer values from string using sscanf()?

Tags: string, parsing, date, integer, scanf

I have a temp string as:
temp = "2014 Jan 16 01 12 59 OP grs0";

I want to retrieve year, month, date, hour, minute and second from this string by using sscanf() and any other way possible.

I have some dummy code as:

```
     int ret_count = 0;

     char discard_msg_type[ENTRY_SIZE]=" ";  /* message type is irrelevant */

    *hour = *minute = *second = *month = *day = *year = -1 ;   /* All these are integer    pointers */ 

     ret_count = sscanf(temp,"%d %s %d %s %d %d %d",year,month,
                                day,discard_msg_type,
                                hour,minute,second);
```

After the execution I was expecting the ret_count value as 7, but it is coming out as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have type mismatch problems between the format string and the data:

```
Data:      "2014 Jan 16 01 12 59 OP grs0"
Format:    "%d   %s  %d %s %d %d %d"
```

You also have type mismatch problems between the format string and the arguments:

```
Format:    "%d   %s   %d   %s    %d   %d   %d"
Variables:  int* int* int* char* int* int* int*
```

You will need to fix both.  For example:

```
int yy, dd, hh, mm, ss;
char mmm[6];

if (sscanf(temp, "%d %s %d %d %d %d", &yy, mmm, &dd, &hh, &mm, &ss) != 6)
    ...report format error...
else if ((*month = map_month_name(mmm)) == -1)
    ...report unrecognized month name...
else
{
    *year   = yy;
    *day    = dd;
    *hour   = hh;
    *minute = mm;
    *second = ss;
}
```

Where `map_month_name()` might be:

```
int map_month_name(char const *mmm)
{
    static char const *months[] =
    {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(months)/sizeof(months[0]); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(mmm, months[i]) == 0)
            return i + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```